# Modify hosts file from AutoIT script executed from Selenium

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, autoit

I am trying to change out my hosts file based on whichever environment I run my script in. It looks like what I'm needing to do is run the commands as admin (elevated privileges), I just cannot seem to find out how to do that in AutoIT.

Here is an example of the call from Selenium:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("C:\HostSwitcher.exe " + C:\Scripts + " " + "QA2");
```

Here is my code in AutoIT:

```
$filePath = $CmdLine[1]
$env = $CmdLine[2]


Run(@comspec & " /c DEL %WINDIR%\SYSTEM32\DRIVERS\ETC\HOSTS")

if $env = "Dev" then
    Run(@comspec & " /c COPY "&$filePath&"hostFiles\DevHost.txt %WINDIR%\SYSTEM32\DRIVERS\ETC\hosts")
endif

if $env = "QA2" then
    Run(@comspec & " /c COPY "&$filePath&"hostFiles\QA2Host.txt %WINDIR%\SYSTEM32\DRIVERS\ETC\hosts")
endif
```

How would I tell AutoIT to run as admin?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a starting note, your account should have elevated privileges.

As far as I know you have options here:

1. the most desired and safe one

   Run your Java application (IntelliJ, Eclipse) as Administrator. This way, any processes spawn or executed by it would be ran with elevated privileges (this works as a chain reaction in Windows and not only).
2. Run it with elevated privileges

   `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("runas /profile /user:Administrator \"C:\HostSwitcher.exe " + C:\Scripts + " " + "QA2");`

Comment: FYI for future readers, running Eclipse as Administrator did the trick for me. Thanks